# Tokem ERC20 eth accept payament usdt

Tags: solidity, usdt, usdc

In my smart contract (in moment erc20), is possible create payment function receive eth
I would like to receive usdt (or usdc) and not eth, how could I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Work in the following order.

1. Use the USDT contract's approve function to allow the user USDT to be sent to your contract address.
2. Write a payment function in your contract. The user calls this function. In the payment function, the USDT corresponding to the payment amount is transferred to your contract.

Comment: my contract is this, I would like to buy a function with the cost of 1 usdt (require 1usdt), could you show me how to do it?
https://0bin.net/paste/HyuNGncD#J3GBv8YMMYDDlYmThQdbSlt65PS3vAaeRiW15UZe-9o

Comment: contract USDTPaymentContract {
    ERC20 usdt;

    function initialize(address usdt_) external {
        usdt = ERC20(usdt_);
    }
    
    function payment(uint amount) external {
        usdt.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    }
}

In initialize, the USDT contract address is passed.

Comment: My new contrct is https://0bin.net/paste/i2Rqadoy#kETEOOe9NJBLh5nsczx1YvXk-xRhnF/3uEIRSKXFsrJ 
How can I do to test? Since in the remix I don't have usdt for testing?